# What laws prohibit dirty water and poor sewage systems at apartment complexes in California?

Tags: landlord, tenant, water

What law requires habitable living conditions that require clean water and no bad sewage smells coming from the bathroom at an apartment?

Answer (score 4):

> What law requires habitable living conditions that require clean water and no bad sewage smells coming from the bathroom at an apartment?

The landlord's *implied warranty of habitability* is mentioned in [sections 1942.3(b), 1954.06(i) of the California Civil Code](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displayText.xhtml?division=3.&chapter=2.&part=4.&lawCode=CIV&title=5.). It can be adduced also from other sections such as 1942.4(a)(1) regarding the "*endanger[ment of] the life, limb, health, property, safety, or welfare of the public or the occupants of the dwelling*".

Additionally, see [*Green v. Superior Court*, 10 Cal.3d 616, 627, 637 (1974)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/197462610cal3d6161589):

> [P]ublic policy compels landlords to bear the primary responsibility
> for maintaining safe, clean and habitable housing in our state [...]
> This implied warranty of habitability [...] does mean that "bare
> living requirements" must be maintained.

[*Grabowiec v. Schopmeyer*, CoA (unpublished, March 2014)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/incaco20140317034), cites precedents in the sense that "*the leaking of sewage from the bathroom plumbing, [...] lack of proper plumbing connection to sewage system in bathroom [has] supported a breach of implied warrant of habitability claim*" (brackets added).

Comment: I’m still wondering if there is anything in the Water Code that would provide for an actionable right for an individual or an implied warranty or guarantee therefor.